# Detecting errors from cross domain AJAX request when the host doesn't respond

Tags: jquery

I'm testing functionality that handles the UI when our notification server is down.  The loading code actually works fine, however if the server is unreachable then none of the callbacks seem to fire.

Here is the loading code and a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xykKf/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:51437/Scripts/framework.js",
        dataType: "script",
        error: handleError,
        success: function () {
            if (!("OFrame" in window)) {
                handleError();
            } else {
                alert("success");
            }
        }            
    });

    function handleError() {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

If you run this (I intentionally use localhost so that the request will fail) no callbacks will fire, but the request will fail.  How can I effectively handle cross domain requests that fail to return a response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the intended behavior.

> Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and
>   cross-domain JSONP requests.

Error callbacks do not get triggered for cross-domain script and cross-domain jsonp requests.

If there was a workaround that worked consistently jQuery would probably have already implemented it.

Comment: Is it recommended to use a setTimeout to handle an error and cancel the timeout in the success callback?

Comment: That could work, though it wouldn't prevent the error in the console. Also, how long should you wait with a setTimeout?

Comment: @Parker `$.ajax` already has a `timeout` option that might be suitable.

Comment: Note however that *"script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after the timeout period."* All the timeout will do is prevent the success from being called, and result in the error callback being called, regardless of whether or not it was actually successful.

Comment: Using the `timeout` property works but it seems like such a hack.